# Why is my AngularJS function is not running?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following AngularJS code and it is not working.  I have created the module as well as the Controller, what have I missed?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myapp = angular.module("Mymodule", []);

        myapp.controller("mycontroller", function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Hello from angular controller";
        });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: `<body ng-app="Mymodule">`

Comment: Thanks its work for me...

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the same name in you `ng-app` as in your module decleration. So either this:

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", ...)
```

Or this:

```
<body ng-app="Mymodule" >
```

Although I'd prefer the former, since it conforms to naming conventions. Your module names should start with a lowercase letter. Check out the [style guide.](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide#modules)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the appropriate model name it will work.

```
<body ng-app="Mymodule" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body ng-app="Mymodule">
```